# Arrow Navigation In PTable

Tags: python, sql

I'm making a project for school about a car database. I use the module PTable to display the cars and i want to know if i can and how to use something like *questionary* to select the cars that is going to be removed, with arrow navigation:

```
questionary.select(
    "What car do you want to remove?",
    choices=[
            *table goes here i asume*
    ]).ask()
```

How would i go about this?

This is what i have now:

```
cur = cursor.execute("SELECT id, brand, price, year, licensePlate, isLeasingCar from cars")
t = PrettyTable(["ID", "Brand", "Price [kr.]", "Year", "License plate", "Is car leased?"])
for row in cur:
    if row[5]:
        leasing = "Ja"
    else:
        leasing = "Nej"
    t.add_row([row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], leasing])
print(t)
questionary.select(
    "What car do you want to remove?",
    choices=[

    ]).ask()
```

I use: 
import questionary
from prettytable import PrettyTable

Comment: `NameError` - what is `questionary` - what does `ask()` do? what imports do you use?

Comment: I use:
import questionary
 and from prettytable import PrettyTable

Comment: Hi @MagnusThomsen, you might want to add that information to the question by editing it instead of replying in a comment.

Comment: Okay thanks, will do that